# Missing constraint en interface builder

Tags: swift2, swift

Estoy tratando de entender porque xCode dice que me falta un constraint para la posición y, si ya tengo un constraint:

```
View.Top = Top Layout Guide.Bottom * 1 + 0
```

[image: Imagen de xCode]

Comment: Podrías mostrar una imagen de la estructura de tus vistas y poner un nombre a cada View?

Answer (score 1):

Igual te puede ayudar utilizar esta libreria, sirve para que sea mas facil utilizar constraints. Se llama snapkit, http://snapkit.io/ Esta en github tambien, https://github.com/SnapKit Te dejo un ejemplo de como se utiliza:

```
let box = UIView()
superview.addSubview(box)

box.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
    make.top.equalTo(superview).offset(20)
    make.left.equalTo(superview).offset(20)
    make.bottom.equalTo(superview).offset(-20)
    make.right.equalTo(superview).offset(-20)
}
```